# Is there any way to track GPS device without WiFi, Bluetooth, internet?

Tags: gps, tracking-devices

I am trying to develop a security gadget which can be wearable. But can be operated remotely from any location in the world using its GPS ID. Don't want to use WiFi, Bluetooth, the internet or any communication protocol.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to IoT.SE. If you want that gadget to communicate / be operated remotely of sorts you cannot rule out "any communication protocol" - you can't make an omelette without breaking eggs. You really need to be more specific what you want to achieve and put only realistic restrictions to that.

Comment: Please add some reference about GPS ID, unfortunately Google show so many results, I cannot decide which one is relevant.

Comment: What kind of communication do you have in mind? Satellite, 4G, something like that?

Comment: Have a look at this post with all its answers: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/268571/methods-of-sending-gps-position

Comment: Please refrain from rolling back edits that improve the spelling.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to develop a security gadget which can be wearable.

Congratulations. This sounds like a good idea. The first thing to worry about is power. Wait! Actually, that is the second. The fist is whether you want to create a new device, or whether it might not be better/easier to develop an app for a smartphone.

> But can be operate remotely from any location in the world using its GPS ID.

You need to define “operate”.

I am going to make a guess that you are trying to track the device (which is ***NOT*** the same as tracking the device owner), by their GPS location. Is that all that you want to do? Just track the wearer? Or maybe you want them to be able to trigger an alarm? Anything else?

If you want to make your own gadget, then [AdaFruit](https://www.adafruit.com) have a good line in [wearables](https://www.adafruit.com/category/65)  which you can use as a basis.

> Don't want to use WiFi, Bluetooth, internet or any communication protocol. 
>   Then you won’t be able to track the device. GPS does not allow sending data over the GPS satellite, only recovering position and time data from it.

If you need to send the position back to a server (and I am sure that you do), then the following can be used, in increasing order of cost:

- WiFi
- Packet data / SMS
- satellite

**WiFi** : cheap, and free in many places, but you can’t guarantee coverage.  Places like Singapore might have almost countrywide coverage of free wifi, but otherwise, I would not expect it, even in big cities like London or New York. In fact, for a security device, you would ***never*** want to rely on free wifi.

**Packet data / SMS** :  depending on the data/call plans, choose whether it is cheaper to send data as TCP or use a RESTful API. If that seems too expensive, consider using SMS – lots of existing apps do, but many of them do it for legacy reasons and have been doing so for decades.

**Satellite** : is pushing it slightly for “wearable”, but it could be done as a belt, and easily in a small rucksack. It is also  your only option (except for some tricky radio stuff, but that it beyond my ken).

I have had lots of fun with Skywave’s offerings (they have now rebranded as OrbComm), and you might like to look at the [IDP_800](http://www.orbcomm.com/en/hardware/devices/skywave-idp-800).

Read the [datasheet](http://www.orbcomm.com/PDF/datasheet/IDP-800-Trailer-Tracking.pdf).

Mass: with batteries: 1.3 Kg (with integrated antenna  Dimensions : 43.2 cm x 14.7 cm x 2.5 cm  and it runs on 6 AA batteries, which can be bought almost anywhere. I send only one 50 byte message a day & they tell me that I can except a three year battery life. Their units generally cost US $500 - $1,000 (with discount for bulk purchases), and their airtime rates are competitive.

The device has built in GPDS and is fully programmable in the [LUA](https://www.lua.org/) scripting language

> Is their any way to do it.

Please define “it”. To communicate without communications? No (obviously). To develop a tracker? Yes (as shown by the many different kinds which are already available).

If you update your question with more details of what you are trying to achieve, then I will update this answer, and others might answer too. You have to give us more information and help us to help you.